# sending bulk Sms through plivo API in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have got the mobile numbers in an array.
Right now I am looping thru the numbers and sending the sms.
I saw this example where we need to separate the numbers with  "<" (e.g., 14156667777<14157778888<14158889999) to send bulk sms. But I dont know how to do it with an array.

```
   var sendSMS = Promise.promisify(notifier.sendSMS);
    var text = req.params.textmessage;
    Doctor.getAllDoctorNumber(function(err, doc){
    if(err)
    res.sendStatus(500);
    else
    {
     for(i=0;i<doc.length;i++)
     {
         sendSMS(doc[i], text)
     }
    }
```

Comment: you can push all the sendSMS promises into an array and use promise.all to resolve all in parallel. [link](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html), which is useful for when you want to wait for more than one promise to complete

```
Doctor.getAllDoctorNumber(function(err, doc){
    if(err)
        res.sendStatus(500);
    else {
        var sms = [];
         for(i=0;i<doc.length;i++)
         {
            smo.push( sendSMS(doc[i], text));
         }
        Promise.all(sms).then(function() {
            console.log("all sms are sent");
        });         
    }
});
```